# How can I check if viewport is on the top with JavaScript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to detect if the user view is on the top of the viewport of the browser. If the user viewport is on the top of the browser I will add some classes in my navigation. If he is not I will delete the classes. Can someone tell me how can I do this? Thank's in advance.

Comment: Assuming you mean that the browser is scrolled to the top, check `$(window).scrollTop() == 0;`

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!window.scrollY) {
  // user is at top
}
```

To test when user scrolls to top:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
   if (!window.scrollY) {
      // user at top
      // add classes here or call some function
   }
});
```

If you want to keep the classes while user scrolls a down a little, you may do something like

```
if (window.scrollY < viewportOffset) {
  // viewportOffset is height till you want to show classes
  // add classes
} else {
  // remove classes
}
```